# How to get out of infinite loop in tomcat for MySQLNonTransientConnectionException No operations allowed after connection closed

Tags: tomcat, jdbc

I overrode a war file in tomcat with out removing the previous war file.  I went to the logs the same error is in a loop with the description:

MySQLNonTransientConnectionException No operations allowed after connection closed

I have delete the war file, stopped and started tomcat.  The loop continues to pummel the logs.

Does anyone know how to stop these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like a fluke.  I have not seen this error since.  If you have let me know and I will reopen.